# What are the upgrade paths for the academy?

Tags: kings-bounty-the-legend

The academy only shows what unit type it upgrades to for existing units already in the army, and only if you've already unlocked the correct race and level upgrades. Can anyone provide or link to a diagram or table (or the data in any other form, really) showing what upgrades to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since so far nobody proposed any answer, this is an attempt to create a list of the upgrade paths here as community-wiki, so **please edit stuff into this list if you find anything**.

- Beholders -> Evil Beholders
- Pirates -> Sea Dogs -> Ghost Pirates
- Priests -> Inquisitors
- Robbers -> Marauders
- Swordsmen -> Guardsmen
- Griffins -> Royal Griffins
- Archmages -> Rune Mages
- Zombies -> Decaying Zombies
- Ghosts -> Cursed Ghosts
- Orcs -> Orc Trackers
- Goblins -> Goblin Shamans
- Vampires -> Ancient Vampires

Sources:

- Editor's gameplay
- http://forum.1cpublishing.eu/showthread.php?t=16540